# Why does not Atom recognize other files in the same directory?

Tags: python

I want to use some text files that I have in the same directory in my script. But Atom always gives me this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'comments.txt'
[Finished in 0.156s]
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

This is my code

```
with open('comments.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNames = [line.strip() for line in f]
print(myNames)
```

It works on other IDE's such as Pycharm and sublime text. I also tried it on the python idle.

In Atom, it only works when I give it the full path. But I want it to only use the project path.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the person that wrote Atom knowns why they did it the way they did.

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Script package, go to File>Settings (or CTRL+,) then open the Packages tab. Find script and open its Settings menu. The first setting is "Change Current Working Directory (CWD) Behavior." Change the value from "First project directory" to "Directory of script."

[image: Image of Settings Page]

Answer (score 0):

It could be that atom changes a file path.

Run a file or command to check

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

This will tell you which dir you are working from.

Use this in your script to change dir

```
os.chdir(PATH_TO_DIR)
```

or write full file path

Comment: Hmm, weird, it's in the first folder of the directory instead of the folder where all my files are.